# How to automatically login user with OpenID?

Tags: java, openid, jopenid

As far as I see, normally OpenID libraries like jopenid show how you can create a link on a webpage that redirects users to a provider, and then have this provider forward them to a specified page with the authentication information.

I also see that whenever I visit site like StackOverflow, I do not have to click the "log me in" button. Once I log in with my Google account, it remembers me.

How can I achieve this effect, so that I don't have to ask users to log in every time? How does StackOverflow do it?

I am taking my first baby steps with OpenID, so please have mercy if I am getting something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have verified the user's identity via OpenID you can issue them a persistent cookie, one that doesn't expire or has a long expiration.  Use this cookie to authenticate them on subsequent requests, renewing it (extending any expiration) as needed.

Comment: Do you happen to know how StackExchange does it?

Comment: You're probably thinking of the global network authentication, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/.  That's probably overkill for what you need.  A cookie with a long expiration that automatically renews should be sufficient for a single site.  What they are doing is automatically logging you into a *related* site without requiring reauthorization.  That's slightly different and more complex.